# Program LED with just USB port

Tags: c#, usb, hardware

I want to control LED with C# using only USB port. I don't want to attach any other device with USB. I just want to attach LED directly to USB port pins and program it (blink etc). How can i do that? I am new to hardware programming and it will be my first program.

EDIT: I can do it already (blink LED) using `printer port` by attaching one led pin to `data pin` and other to `ground`. How can i do the same with USB port? My motherboard does not have a printer port. USB is the only option.

Comment: You can't do that.  LED's are not a USB device, so there is no communication to be had.  You can probably get a LED to light up (or burn out or catch fire) by hooking it up, but that's about it.

Comment: You might find it easier if you have an old Parallel port (printer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible.

```
4 usb pins

| | | |  
| | | |  
1 2 3 4

1: +5V
2: D-
3: D+
4: Ground

To trun on LED connect with 1 and 4
```

Current on Data pins is too low therefore LED will never turn on if connected with `5V` and any Data pin. Hence LED can not be controlled directly using data pins on USB port

Answer (score 4):

Many mainboards will permanently supply USB ports with current.

You could theoretically put the USB controller into some suspend mode and back again but this is bad.

You'd need some sort of controller to accept commands over USB then some discrete elements to open/close current from the permanent USB supply and let it reach your LED.

Comment: If you're going to try to toggle the LED, you have to have a USB controller to decode the USB packets from the USB host which Windows directly controls.

Also, depending on the LED, you will probably want an a resistor between the control circuit and LED.

Interesting experiment: take a power supply and attach the LED to the positive and negative leads.  Wait and watch what happens.

Comment: Just remember to put in a current limiting resistor, else will fry the poor diode - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED_circuit

Comment: Also check out the nominal voltage and consumption current. With some very strong LEDs there is some risk of burning out the USB controller.

Comment: LED do work with USB cable when its wires are connected to pin 1 and 4 of USB. What i want is to control the blinking of LED. Turning off USB power is not a good solution. There should be a way to control it, may be using data pins

Comment: There is a way to control it...  With a USB controller...  :-)  What you're missing is that USB is a true bus and not a simple endpoint/port.

Answer (score 4):

You really can't do this. You can do it with a parallel port because you have individual control over the data pins. With USB, you only have control over the data the rides on top of the USB protocol. It's likely that protocol is being run in firmware by a chip on the motherboard anyway, so there's most likely no way to do what you want to do, short connecting the LED across the power pins and toggling the USB bus power, which you should NOT do for a whole variety of reasons.

Just get an Arduino or something. In the long run it will be a lot easier and be more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

> I can do it already (blink LED) using printer port...

OK, so why not buy a [cheap USB based printer port](http://www.google.com/products?q=usb+lpt&hl=en&scoring=p) and use that? Since you already have the LPT port code working, this gives you a transparent solution.

Comment: I bought that board. I can not program it like i programmed the real printer port on another pc :(

Comment: Sounds like that should be another SO question. "I have C# LED blinking code that works with the built in LPT port, but doesn't work with the GeeWizBang Model 1234 USB printer port. What is wrong?"

Comment: With a real LPT printer port you have direct control over the port.
But with a USB LPT printer port the usb driver is acting as another layer of abstraction -- and trying to use raw printer port commands fail because the usb driver is not programmed to allow low-level access to the printer port.  You either need a custom usb driver (lsusb, etc) or you need to try making low-level calls the usb driver itself.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a PIC microcontroller . The 18f series can directly interface led's over the usb . It is also possible to code using c# and use only the USB port to control the led . I'm guessing you actually want to control the led and not just get it to glow .